# PDF2SVG:Use pdfbox and batik to generate svg files, but no text

Tags: java, pdf, svg, pdfbox, batik

Use Apache pdfbox and batik to generate svg files, but all texts in the generated svg files become paths
This is

```
Printable page = new PDFPrintable(document);
SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(ctx, false);
page.print(svgGenerator, pageFormat, i);
svgGenerator.stream(svgFName,true);
```

If the svg file generated with pdfbox and batik cannot generate text What method do I need to use to generate an svg file from pdf using java, and text exists in the svg

Comment: Yes PDFBox doesn't keep font information when printing. Historically this was because the java font engine was crappy.

Comment: I see...but if I want to use java to generate svg from pdf, and there is text in it, what can I do?@TilmanHausherr

Comment: There's a guy who managed to use the java font engine for output, it's described here https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8265761 but it's not part of PDFBox, you need to have some understanding how PDFBox works inside.

Comment: And this one https://github.com/AlexanderScherbatiy/pdfbox/commit/b806d44f9514a7b5fededfa49c98ad2858b93a92 from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5093

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Another problem is that when there are pictures in the pdf I want to print, if I set dpi in printable, the entire pdf will be converted into pictures, and the generated svg file will be a<image>. However, if the dpi is not set, the image quality in the generated svg file will be poor if the method described in my description is used for printing. What can I do to improve the quality of the generated images without converting the entire pdf into a<image>.

Comment: Maybe that new question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234455/poor-image-quality-when-using-svgconverter-in-batik-to-convert-svg-to-png

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks a lot, I can solve my problem by adding RenderingHints.Key【KEY_RESOLUTION_VARIANT】 to pdfPrintable

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, sorry to bother you. But I have a problem. I used the pdfbox to print a Chinese pdf file on the mac, and there was no problem. Then I deploy the same code to the server, print the same pdf file, and the printed Chinese characters will become boxes. I want to know whether this is due to the lack of a corresponding font library on the server.

Comment: Likely PDF without embedded fonts, and missing fonts on the server. Please install chinese fonts on the server. Check the logs, these mention that is missing.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, about your previous mention that PDFBox will not retain font information when printing, i wonder whether all information of Text will not be saved, or just font? Thanks

Comment: The printing is just raster or vector graphics.